# Xpath combine two @class elements

Tags: xpath

I want to find the following element on a web site: **//a[@class="a-link-normal"]/@href**
inside this element: **//div[@class="s-result-list s-search-results sg-row"]**.
I tried this one: 
//*[contains(@class='s-result-list s-search-results sg-row') and contains(@class='a-link-normal')]"))
but it doesn't work, xpath helper shows "invalid xpath expression".
Probably the solution is quite simple, but i can't make it work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a sample of code or url. It's a bit hard to work blindfolded.

Answer (score 1):

So, Amazon. You're looking for this (you didn't use the correct div) :

```
//div[@class="s-main-slot s-result-list s-search-results sg-row"]//a[@class="a-link-normal"]
```